# How copy a folder by recursion without include source folder label inside dest folder?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I use the code below to copy a folder by recursion. Works fine, but exists a problem even least to me, because source folder label also is being included inside dest folder after copy, and i not want it. In this moment what happens is this:

**SRC Folder:**

```
C:\MyTest
  -firstfolder
  -secondfolder
  -- secondfolderFile
```

**DEST Folder (after copy):**

```
C:\NewTest
  -MyTest
  -firstfolder
  -secondfolder
  -- secondfolderFile
```

---

And then i need that in dest folder only stays:

```
C:\NewTest
  -firstfolder
  -secondfolder
  -- secondfolderFile
```

How make this using the following code?

```
program testCopyRecursion;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  ShellAPI,
  SysUtils;

function CopyFolder(const SrcFolder, DestFolder: String; iFileOp: Integer;
  OverWrite: Boolean; ShowDialog: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  MyFOStruct: TSHFileOpStruct;
  Src, Dest: String;
  ResultVal: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  Src := SrcFolder;
  Dest := DestFolder;

  if not DirectoryExists(Dest) then
    ForceDirectories(Dest);

  if (Src = '') or ((iFileOp <> FO_DELETE) and (Dest = '')) or
    (CompareText(Src, Dest) = 0) then
    Exit;

  if Src[Length(Src)] = '\' then
    SetLength(Src, Length(Src) - 1);
  Src := Src + #0#0;

  if (Dest <> '') and (Dest[Length(Dest)] = '\') then
    SetLength(Dest, Length(Dest) - 1);
  Dest := Dest + #0#0;

  FillChar(MyFOStruct, SizeOf(MyFOStruct), 0);

  with MyFOStruct do
  begin
    Wnd := 0;

    wFunc := iFileOp;
    pFrom := @Src[1];
    pTo := @Dest[1];

    fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;

    if not OverWrite then
      fFlags := fFlags or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;
    if not ShowDialog then
      fFlags := fFlags or FOF_SILENT;
  end;

  try
    MyFOStruct.fAnyOperationsAborted := False;
    MyFOStruct.hNameMappings := nil;
    ResultVal := ShFileOperation(MyFOStruct);
    Result := (ResultVal = 0);
  finally
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    CopyFolder('C:\MyTest', 'C:\NewTest', FO_COPY, True, False);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;

end.
```

Comment: Recursion is when the module calls itself to execute a part of the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are copying the `C:\MyTest` folder itself into the `C:\NewTest` folder, rather than just copying what is inside of `C:\MyTest`. Try setting the source path to `'C:\MyTest\*'` instead to copy only what is inside of `C:\MyTest`.

And FYI, you don't need the call to `ForceDirectories()`, as `SHFileOperation()` creates the destination folder if it does not already exist.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shfileopstructw) even says so:

> Copy and Move operations can specify destination directories that do not exist. In those cases, the system attempts to create them and normally displays a dialog box to ask the user if they want to create the new directory. To suppress this dialog box and have the directories created silently, set the `FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR` flag in `fFlags`.

Try something more like this:

```
program testCopyRecursion;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows, ShellAPI, SysUtils;

function CopyFolder(const SrcFolder, DestFolder: String;
  OverWrite: Boolean; ShowDialog: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  MyFOStruct: TSHFileOpStruct;
  Src, Dest: String;
begin
  Result := False;

  if (SrcFolder = '') or (DestFolder = '') or
     (CompareText(SrcFolder, DestFolder) = 0) then
    Exit;

  Src := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SrcFolder) + '*'#0;
  Dest := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DestFolder) + #0;

  FillChar(MyFOStruct, SizeOf(MyFOStruct), 0);

  with MyFOStruct do
  begin
    wFunc := FO_COPY;
    pFrom := PChar(Src);
    pTo := PChar(Dest);
    fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
    if not OverWrite then
      fFlags := fFlags or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;
    if not ShowDialog then
      fFlags := fFlags or FOF_SILENT;
  end;

  Result := (SHFileOperation(MyFOStruct) = 0);
end;

begin
  try
    CopyFolder('C:\MyTest', 'C:\NewTest', True, False);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```